# tableview button not using correct indexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, button, tags, tableview

I have a button in each cell in my `tableview`. Basically I'm saving the cell's `indexPath in the button's tag in the`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIButton *expandPhoto = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    expandPhoto.tag = indexPath.row;
    [expandPhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(expand:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is, when i scroll down the button's `indexPath` resets.
I've searched alot in the internet but I'm stuck with this problem for days.

Comment: how did you know indexpath changed?Add the code.USing storyboard?

Comment: Yes I'm using a storyboard and I know the indexPath is not what it is supposed to be with NSLogs (It shows indexPath 0 when it should show 6, shows 1 when it should show 7, etc. Also, I'm using prototype cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIButton *expandPhoto = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    [expandPhoto setTag:indexPath.row];
    [expandPhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(expand:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)expand:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) btn.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; 
    int row = indexPath.row;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";` it will reuse the cells so you will get the cell index as 0 when it should show 6, shows 1 when it should show 7, etc..

If you want to get the index as 0,1,....6,7, etc..

Use Like this,

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
```

But it wont reuse the cell.

Comment: the table is empty. i know by the logs tho, that it is loading the correct number of cells.

Comment: I really need to find a solution. Can you please review it?

Comment: what u actually want to do??

Comment: the button is created in the prototype cell

Answer (score 0):

***Custom table view cell is the best approuch to solve this problem here we need to create different the Custom table view cell controller and use this in cellForAtIndexPath tableview Datasource :***

**CustomTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UILabel  *tblViewLabel;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIButton *tblViewBtn;
@end
```

**CustomTableViewCell.m**

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell
@synthesize  tblViewLabel = _tblViewLabel;
@synthesize  tblViewBtn = _tblViewBtn;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString 
*)reuseIdentifier

{

  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

 if (self) {
    // Initialization code


   _tblViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 50, 30)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_tblViewLabel];
    [_tblViewLabel release];

    _tblViewBtn         = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    _tblViewBtn.frame   = CGRectMake(100, 5, 200, 20);
    [_tblViewBtn.titleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.tag]];

    [_tblViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(tblBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_tblViewBtn];
    [_tblViewBtn release];

}
return self;

}


- (void)tblBtnPressed :(UIButton *)btn {

  NSLog(@"Here %d button is pressed.",btn.tag);

}



- (void)dealloc {
[_tblViewLabel release];
[_tblViewBtn release];
[super dealloc];

}
@end
```

//------------------------//

```
Here In Your Previous controller's cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

}

cell.tblViewLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

[cell.tblViewBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cell.tblViewBtn.tag = indexPath.row;


return cell;

}
```